# The half shekel and atonement for the soul

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, parashat-ki-tisa, golden-calf-egel, kaparah-atonement

In [parashas Ki Sissa](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.30.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), G-d instructs Moshe to collect from all the people, half a shekel:

> When thou dost take the sum of the children of Yisra᾽el after their
> number, then shall they give every man a ransom for his soul to the
> Lord, when thou dost number them; that there be no plague among them,
> when thou dost number them.

The Torah uses different words to describe what the half shekel is for.

1. a ransom for his soul to the L-rd (v.12)
2. an atonement for the soul (v. 15/16)

However, the words "atonement for the soul" seems to be used more than "ransom for his soul".

In posuk 12, the Torah writes:

> that there be no plague among them, when thou dost number them.

However, the [Sifsei Chakhamim](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.30.15?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Siftei%20Chakhamim&lang2=en) seems to understand this to mean that it does not serve as an atonement for the soul.

> So that you not be struck. . . But it does not mean to atone for your sins, like other atonements mentioned in the Torah. [Rashi knows this] because [otherwise,] why is the atonement connected to the counting?

**Are there meforshim that explain why the Torah uses the words "atonement for the soul" and what this implies?** What is the deeper meaning behind this? Was it really atonement for the soul, atonement for the golden calf? And how to reconcile the words of the Sifsei Chakhamim with the posuk itself?

---

<sup>*I've thought about the [Yerushalmi](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shekalim.1.1.6?ven=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_translation_and_commentary_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that teaches us that the gold of the cover of the Ark was an atonement for the golden calf. So I thought, maybe the half shekel was also an atonement for the golden calf, since everybody needed to give his part (however, the gold was used, and the half shekel was not made from gold. The [Chasam Sofer](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shekalim.1.1.6?lang=bi&with=Chidushei%20Chatam%20Sofer&lang2=en) on that Yerushalmi seems to explain that it would be logical that since the people gave their gold for the egel to be made, that the cover of the ark was also made from gold, as an atonement. So it seems logical to me that other objects could also serve as an atonement, including the half shekel).*</sup>

Comment: https://alhatorah.org/Half_Shekels_%E2%80%93_For_Census_or_Tabernacle/2
I assume you've seen all the sources quoted here. but this might help anyway

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Yes, I saw it yesterday before typing up this question. The Shadal says that the people had an עין הרע and that the shekel was an atonement for that. Abarbanel asserts that a direct headcount might lead to plague due to the evil eye. Still, for me, this is hard to understand. What exactly was the atonement itself? And why did it atone?

Comment: Great questions!

Comment: The whole entire thing and all the Tikkun is all the Moshe-Mashiach-Tzaddik versus the Amalek-S"M-Impostors-ErevRav so for example KPRH has the Hei of Teshuva against KPR Apostasy Indifference Mediocrity Materialism Marxism.  By being chozer Tikunei Zohar Sifrei Breslev etc. with all Chazal and with Strong Devotions you will understand everything Na Nach PS

Comment: And a friend told me: Noach's ark had kofer inside and outside, but the ark of babe Moshe, only on the outside, so he wouldn't have to smell it.
NNNNM

Comment: I am sorry, but cannot understand what exactly you mean. What has that to do with the shekel?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Sichot_Avodat_Levi.46

Comment: @shmosel that can qualify as an answer if you want (incl. translation pls).

Comment: @Shmuel did you see this midrash? https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Ki_Tisa.10.1. Came across it last night, half asleep, still digesting it as it is very deep. Does it help with your question?

Comment: @RabbiKaii No, not that one. Thx for pointing it out to me. I like the idea of the ten commandments and the ten gerah.

Comment: @Shmuel don't just read 10, but keep going, the discussion on this idea is long

Comment: Oh and look what just came up :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGGFGNX9Oiw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many sources that interpret atonement in the ordinary sense. The [Yerushalmi](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shekalim.2.3.5?lang=bi) and [Tanchuma](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Ki_Tisa.10.1?lang=bi) link it to the golden calf (also hinted to in [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.30.16?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.30.16&lang2=bi)). [Some](https://www.sefaria.org/Shadal_on_Exodus.30.11.1) say that it's an atonement for the evil eye caused by counting, [or](https://www.sefaria.org/Sichot_Avodat_Levi.46) to counteract the additional scrutiny brought about when individuals are singled out from the community.

But Rashi [seems](https://www.lahak.org/templates/lahak/article_cdo/aid/4306672/jewish/-.htm) to take a novel approach in his main interpretation. He reads "when you count them" as implying that the counting itself was done via the coins, so as to avoid the issue of counting people altogether, which requires him to loosely define "atonement"as a sort of preventative measure. Perhaps that's why he offers the [second](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.30.15?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.30.15.1&lang2=bi#:%7E:text=of%20the%20census.-,Another%20explanation,-of%20%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%9C) explanation, that it's called an atonement because it funded the communal sacrifices which brought atonement.

On a deeper level, the Lubavitcher Rebbe [explains](https://www.lahak.org/templates/lahak/article_cdo/aid/2993694/jewish/-.htm) that these sacrifices are uniquely related to the golden calf since it was a communal sin. The world was originally created in a state of perfection, but it was ruined by the sin of the Tree of Knowledge, which impacted not only Adam and Chava, but the entire world and all future generations. The Jews were [cleansed](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.146a.1?lang=bi) of this contamination when they received the Torah at Sinai, but with the sin of the golden calf, they [reverted](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Bereshit.88.292) to a state of contamination at the community level, affecting even those who had no part in it, like the tribe of Levi and [Moshe](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.7?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.32.7.2&lang2=bi) himself. That's why the half-shekel went specifically toward communal sacrifices (and why it was a fixed rate for everyone), because it was a communal atonement.

But this is only skimming the surface of a classic topic in Chassidus. There are many in-depth Maamarim and Sichos on the subject; see [here](https://www.sie.org/templates/sie/article_cdo/aid/2347354/jewish/Likkutei-Sichot-Ki-Sissa.htm) and [here](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2513572/jewish/A-Coin-of-Fire.htm) for some translated examples.

Comment: great job, especially that explanation in Toras Menachem. I have already read the Maamarim, but could not find a satisfying answer in it, in Toras Menachem I did. Thank you! The Rebbe writes: הוצרך להיות ממון ציבור, ושימש עבור קרבנות ציבור ממש - it had to be money given by the public etc... - Rabbi Ken Spiro (Aish) explains that only a small portion of the people worshipped the Egel, how can this be connected to the idea that the whole community needed to give the shekel?

Comment: There are many instances where the community is held to task for the mistakes of a minority or an individual, presumably based on the principle of ערבות. See also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10344/6592

Comment: I understand. Interesting. However, does it make sense that even the people that did not worship the Egel, were also punished (for example, their status of being like angels was changed)? In Sefer Nachal Adnich, Rabbi חנסוב, דן בן ראובן explains that after the sin of the Egel, the people weren't able to learn Torah in the same way they ware able when they received it. Is it fair that Shevet HaLevi was affected by that?